# How to avoid two fields with the same name in two different tables to take the same value in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can someone avoid to have two fields with the same name in two different tables to take the same value?
For example, I have table customer:

```
cust_id   telephone   country
  1       03458902     UK  
  2       05868915     DE
```

And on the other hand, I have table seller:

```
seller_id   telephone   country  
  1         07854264     GR  
  2         03458902     ES
```

In this example, the telephone number is unique, thus there shouldn't be the same telephone for a seller and a customer. 
There should be a warning at the insert command:

```
insert into seller values(2,'03458902','ES')
```

I know there should be something like below:

```
create trigger .... before insert on seller
```

But I am not very familiar with the term.
I found an example in MySQL. However I don't know how to change it from MySQL code to SQL code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `unique_telephone_seller`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `unique_telephone_seller` BEFORE INSERT ON `seller`
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     DECLARE c INT;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO c FROM customer WHERE telephone = NEW.telephone;
        IF (c > 0) THEN
           -- abort insert, because foo.username should be NOT NUL
           SET NEW.telephone = NUL;
        END IF;
END
```

Later Edit:

Since everyone is doubting my question, let me explain why I have 2 tables. 
I have to build a telecom database. A customer can have prepaid and postpaid SIMs.
So I have a table with the customer (id, name, address etc.), one table for prepaid SIMs (client_id, phone_no etc) and one table for postpaid SIMs ((client_id, phone_no etc).
A client can have both types of SIMs, or multiples of the same type. That's why I separated the SIMs in 2 tables (and the SIMs have other parameters depending on the type).
So to not have duplicate phone_no, before insert on a table I have to verify if the number is in the other table.

Regards//Cristina

Comment: I think you have a problem with your data model.  Why can't a seller also be a customer?

Comment: This is just an example. Of course a seller can be a customer. But it was simpler to explain it with customer and seller.

Comment: Agree with @GordonLinoff .  If your phone number or whatever is unique then it's your primary key and should not be in two tables.  There should be one table with the phone number and the other bits (customer or seller ID & country) hanging off that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a procedure to check before `INSERT`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sample_Procedure 
    @seller_Id int,
    @telephone VARCHAR(8),  
    @country CHAR(2)
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT cust_id FROM customer WHERE telephone = @telephone)
        SELECT 'This phone number exists in customer table.'
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO seller VALUES(@seller_Id, @telephone, @country) 
RETURN 0
```

Comment: This will not work.  Transactional isolation means that transaction A inserting the phone # cannot check to see if transactions B is doing it also until it is done.  It only works when the duplicate value is already committed.

Comment: True @LoztInSpace. But as long as the transaction is committed before calling this proc, it's fine.

Comment: Yes but is turning your system into a single-user system acceptable?  Maybe, maybe not.  My preference is to not put these limitations in, especially limitations that are not thought about or even identified by current or future developers/product managers.  If you just do it right then nobody has to care about any limitations hidden in the guts of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using INSTEAD OF rather than for requires you to handle the insert logic. Using FOR allows you to issue a rollback instead, and let the insert logic occur regularly.

To fail an entire block, be sure to include it in a transaction.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_table_phone
ON dbo.customer_phone
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.seller_phone p INNER JOIN inserted i ON p.phone = i.phone) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('A phone number exists in seller phone and cannot be inserted',16,1)
    END
END
```

Comment: This will not work all the time. It only works when the duplicate value is already committed and will not prevent simultaneous inserts of the same value in two separate transactions.

Comment: While I agree this should be a single table, opening the query up to read uncommitted would allow you to see those records too. The op would have to decide on what is acceptable - but it is something I had not even mentioned. Thanks.